# Delete class instance from memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, memory, instance

In my program I create an un-ending amount of class instances. the amount depends on how long the program is running. However I don't need the instances at all after a certain code being run. How could i remove them completely from memory?

Simple example code:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

for n in range(1000):
    p = Player('black')
```

Would `del p` in this case completely remove that instance?

Comment: Objects that have no references to them will be collected by the garbage collector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python will remove them from memory for you when they are no longer referred to. If you have `Player` instances that refer to other `Player` instances (ex: `p.teammates = [list of Players]`) you could end up with circular references that may prevent them from being garbage collected. In this case you should consider the [`weakref`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html) module.

for example:

```
>>>sam = Player('blue')
>>>rob = Player('green')
>>>sam.team = [sam, rob]
>>>rob.team = [sam, rob]
>>> #sam and rob may not be deleted because they contain 
>>> #references to eachother so the reference count cannot reach 0
>>>del sam #del is a way to manually dereference an object in an interactive prompt. Otherwise the interpreter cannot know you won't use it again unlike when the entire code is known at the beginning.
>>>print(rob.team[0].color) #this prints 'blue' proving that sam hasn't been deleted yet
blue
```

so how do we fix it?

```
>>>sam = Player('blue')
>>>rob = Player('green')
>>>sam.team = [weakref.ref(sam), weakref.ref(rob)]
>>>rob.team = [weakref.ref(sam), weakref.ref(rob)]
>>> #now sam and rob can be deleted, but we've changed the contents of `p.team` a bit:
>>> #if they both still exist:
>>>rob.team[0]() is sam #calling a `ref` object returns the object it refers to if it still exists
True
>>>del sam
>>>rob.team[0]() #calling a `ref` object that has been deleted returns `None`
None
>>>rob.team[0]().color #sam no longer exists so we can't get his color
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'color'
```

Comment: what if I use an attribute of an instance as parameter for creating another instance? Would this cause the circular references you're talking about? i.e.                              `b = Player(p.color)`

Comment: @BasVelden `p.color` will refer to a string object you created when you created `p`. If multiple `Player` instances refer to the same string, that string will not be deleted until all `Player` instances referring to it are deleted. while this concept is carried across datatypes (if color was a list instead, only one list would exist in memory, with multiple references to it), Strings in particular have a special additional mechanism called [string interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) to help reduce memory usage and copying.

Answer (score 2):

In this instance, `del p` would only remove the *reference* to the `Player` object, so that it can later be picked up by the garbage collector.

However, this also happens when it goes out-of-scope.

In most everyday Python, there is no need to use explicit `del` statements.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way in Python to delete an instance. Instead you can delete references to the instance, and once they are all gone, the object is reclaimed.