# Clear class of all instances?

Tags: python, class, instance

I wrote a program where class instances are created automatically out of input data.
Each time I run the program however, new instances are created but with the same data.

Is there a way to clear a class after the program has run, in order to prevent double instances?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a list of instances when your class is created.

```py
class Foo:
  instances = []
  
  def __init__(self):
    self.__class__.instances.append(self)
```

Then when you want to delete all of the objects of class Foo, you can use `del` to delete them while iterating through the list.

```py
for i,v in enumerate(Foo.instances):
  del v
```

Comment: Thanks! A follow-up question: why did you use enumerate() and not a "regular" iterator, aka 'for i in Foo.instances:'

Comment: It's more of my personal preference to always use enumerate over a "regular" for loop. Then both the iterations and the value is always available if you need to use it.

Comment: I tried both ways, it sadly doesn't work. The instances are still there after the loop...

Comment: I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53729046/delete-class-instance-from-memory) might help.